# mysqldump command not dumping data as gzip?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to backup the database as gzip, but it doesn't work. This is the command:

```
$backup = $location.'/'.$database.'_backup_'.date('Y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'.sql.gz';   
$cmd = "c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root $database | gzip -9 > $backup";
system($cmd);
```

But it doesn't happen anything. If I'm doing it without gzip, it works, why ?

Comment: Damn. I was currently writing a long answer to your 'building the dump in php' questions and when I hit save, it is gone...

Comment: And for this question: what is the output of this command? Do you have gzip on your windows box? And does this piping work on Windows at all?

Comment: @DerVO Piping does work on Windows. This is most likely a `%PATH%` issue.

Comment: I'm running it with XAMPP. So it should work.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just annoyed on Roland asking the same question "How can i do a fricking mysqldump" in 10 different flavors ... and of course on deleting one flavor after I spent 15 minutes in writing an answer and fixing the code. I will try do calm down. @Roland: Add the path to your mysql and gzip executables to the [PATH environment variable](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/). Otherwise your script will only run on the local machine.

Comment: @DerVo - I'm sorry that I deleted that long question, but it seemed to me that it's a bit to complicated to go that way. And also saw that I get no actual answer or tip. I had some questions here that were unanswered since four days ago, so I thought that that one will end up the same, so I decided to delete it before I get some comment like `this question is not ...` and so on, or to get a -1 on it as I did before. Again, sorry for that. And I'm asking the same question over and over again because I didn't got an answer on either of it which could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use full path to `gzip.exe`.